# How can I receive count of elements?

Tags: cypress

test.js:

```
cy.get('.ant-input-number-input')
  .wait(2000)
  .then(($input_field) => {
    const count = $input_field.find('.ant-input-number-input').length;
    cy.log(count)
  })
```

cy.log:

```
log 0
```

I need to get count of elements. But I received '0'. How can I receive count of elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are only finding the length of the element `.ant-input-number-input`, you can do like this:

1. To get the length

```js
cy.get('.ant-input-number-input')
  .should('be.visible')
  .its('length')
  .then((len) => {
    cy.log(len) //prints length
  })
```

2. if you want to add assertions you can do:

```js
//Length equal to 2
cy.get('.ant-input-number-input')
  .should('be.visible')
  .its('length')
  .should('eq', 2)

//Length greater than 2
cy.get('.ant-input-number-input')
  .should('be.visible')
  .its('length')
  .should('be.gt', 2)

//Length greater than or equal to 2
cy.get('.ant-input-number-input')
  .should('be.visible')
  .its('length')
  .should('be.gte', 2)

//Length less than 2
cy.get('.ant-input-number-input')
  .should('be.visible')
  .its('length')
  .should('be.lt', 2)

//Length less than or equal to 2
cy.get('.ant-input-number-input')
  .should('be.visible')
  .its('length')
  .should('be.lte', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
const count = $input_field.find('.ant-input-number-input').its('length')
```

Comment: Not working for reactjs